# Maven release / SVN : E205009: Local, non-commit operations do not take a log message or revision properties

Tags: svn, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

We are trying to setup the maven-release plugin with maven 3.04 and SVN 1.7.7.

When trying to prepare the release, mvn release:prepare we receive the following message :
svn: E205009: Local, non-commit operations do not take a log message or revision properties

Our config is :

```
<scm>
            <developerConnection>scm:svn:svn://hostname/projects/tags/myapp/poms/parent-pom/parent-pom-0.0.1</developerConnection>
</scm>

...

<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <username>myuser</username>
                <password>mypassword</password>
                <tagBase>scm:svn:svn://hostname/projects/tags/projectname/poms/parent-pom</tagBase>
            </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Does anyone have an idea of what can be wrong ?

Many thanks

Patrick

Comment: The username and password attributes should be in your persona ~/.m2/settings.xml file.  At least for the repository definition...

Comment: Also, you should include the output of the "mvn release:prepare -DdryRun=true" command (note that "dryRun" is case sensitive).

Comment: Possibly useful articles would be - http://www.disasterarea.co.uk/blog/?p=490 and http://blog.soebes.de/index.php?/archives/332-The-unknown-creature-The-Maven-Release-Cycle.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the "scm:svn:" part in your tag base configuration. In your example, it should read:

```
 <tagBase>svn://hostname/projects/tags/projectname/poms/parent-pom</tagBase>
```